# How to hook wp_list_pages?

Tags: filters, hooks, wp-list-pages

How can I hook the wp_list_pages function so that it reads a value of a custom field and displays it instead of displaying the page title?

Comment: Where is your custom field stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google Search came up with [this](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_list_pages)

[Source](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_list_pages?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/post-template.php)

Try the following:

```
function wp_list_pages_filter($output) {
    // modify $output here, it's a string of <li>'s by the looks of source
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'wp_list_pages_filter');
```

Comment: but how to replace the title by a custom field value ?

Comment: Title? Do you mean the Widget Title? That can be set by going to `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets` and adding a Pages widget. You can customize the title there.

Comment: It is NOT an array of pages, it is a string.

Comment: Would you please help :)

Comment: @m0r7if3r I see that now.

Comment: the correct answer should be that of @AlxVallejo. To change the titles using the 'wp_list_pages' filter hook would be a hack. You'd need to search for all original titles and replace them one by one with custom titles, using an array  as a reference map or something. Use a custom Walker instead.

Answer (score 7):

A Walker Class extension would be necessary in this case:

```
class My_Custom_Walker extends Walker_page {
function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page) {
    if ( $depth )
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    else
        $indent = '';

    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    $output .= $indent . 
            '<li><div>' . get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single) . '</div></li>';

} // End start_el
} // End Walker Class
```

Then, when you use your **wp_list_pages** function, you would call the class:

```
// Call class:
$My_Walker = new My_Custom_Walker();

$args = array(
    'walker'      => $My_Walker
);

wp_list_pages( $args );
```

Documentation on this subject is a bit scarce so let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

You are able to pass in your own custom walker as one of the args, use this to pass in a walker which extends `Walker_Page` and uses your own custom post title.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just need some help code :)

Comment: What part of my implementation is not clear enough for you to write code?