# add a.parent in wp_list_pages

Tags: wp-list-pages

In relation to question posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/11821/27418), is it possible to have an output to have something like this instead? where `class="parent"` is applied to the hyperlink?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="parent" href="#">Page with Subpages</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a class="parent" href="#">Page with another subpage</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">subsubpage</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

the function below of TheDeadMedic works well for lists:

```
function add_parent_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args )
{
    if ( ! empty( $args['has_children'] ) )
        $css_class[] = 'parent';
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'add_parent_class', 10, 4 );
```

is it possible to use a similar function to target hyperlinks instead of the lists?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42701/how-to-hook-wp-list-pages), you can add a custom Walker class to your `wp_list_pages()` call.  It looks like that's the way to go, since `wp_list_pages()` prints or returns a string.

If you set `$args['echo']` to `false`, you can do some string manipulation before you `echo()` it, but it seems to me that the Walker solution is probably the way to go.

Unfortunately [the Walker documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) looks a little thin.

Comment: thanks, pat. it sure is hard with very little documentation /reference around. i will give the walker approach a try.

Comment: Here's a Walker documentation page with a bit more content: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class .  Good luck!